# How does the prototype chain work?

Tags: javascript

```
var A = {};
var B = Object.create(A);
var C = Object.create(B);
A.isPrototypeOf(C);//returns true
C.isPrototypeOf(A);//returns false
```

In the above code I'm not understanding the reason behind the result of being false in `C.isPrototypeOf(A);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var A = {}; // A inherits Object
var B = Object.create(A); // B inherits A inherits Object
var C = Object.create(B); // C inherits B inherits A inherits Object

// Does C inherit A?
A.isPrototypeOf(C); // true, yes
// C inherits A because    B inherits A    and    C inherits B

// Does A inherit C?
C.isPrototypeOf(A); // false, no
// A only inherits Object
```

Answer (score 3):

`C` is "descended" from `B` which is "descended" from `A`. How could `C` be the prototype of `A`?

As `C` is ultimately inheriting from `A`, and `A` gets nothing from `C`, then it is false that "`C` is the prototype of `A`"