# How does JavaScript maintain the prototype reference?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Looking at the answer to ([How does the prototype chain work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216394/how-does-the-prototype-chain-work)) I can see that there is an inheritance chain. What is happening behind the scenes?

As far as I can tell the prototype property stores a reference to the prototype object? Why does that object not include the prototype's prototype and how is it maintaining that reference instead?

```js
var Parent = function() {
 this.name = 'Parent';
}

Parent.prototype.sayHi = function() {
 console.log('hi');
}

var Child = function() {
 this.name = "Child";
}

Child.prototype = new Parent();

console.log(Parent.prototype); // { sayHi: [Function] }
console.log(Child.prototype); // { name: 'Parent' }
console.log(Child.prototype.prototype); // undefined
```

=============== Answer from below ===============

```
console.log(Parent.prototype); // { sayHi: [Function] }
console.log(Child.prototype); // { name: 'Parent' }
console.log(Child.prototype.__proto__); // { sayHi: [Function] }
```

Comment: That's not a correct output from your code. Create an inline snippet.

Comment: it does "include the prototype's prototype", if you setup such a relationship. in the code shown, there's no tying of Child to Parent, so it would be surprising if they were connected for you...

Comment: Sorry, now it does. But I still get that same output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does that object not include the prototype's prototype and how is it maintaining that reference instead?

Because in your example, the `prototype` of `Child` is also an instance of `Parent`, not another constructor. The `prototype` is a property of the constructor, not a property of each individual instance.

There is another property that does this for each instance, the [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property, but it has almost no sane uses. The ES6 specification also only requires the feature be implemented in web browser, and not necessarily other JavaScript environments.